# Error in Fhirbase api

Tags: hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I want to use Fhirbase api for my project and i refer http://fhirbase.github.io/installation.html (Local) this link to install fhirbase server and follow all the steps which is given in document,

but when i try to execute first api SELECT fhir_create_storage('{"resourceType": "Patient"}'); it's give me error like,

```
ERROR: function fhir_create_storage(unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT fhir_create_storage('{"resourceType": "Patient"}');
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

how i can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to  init plv8 machine by `SET plv8.start_proc = 'plv8_init';`. This should be done on a fresh connection, so reconnect and execute this statement as first one or put it in postgresql.conf. http://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/doc/plv8.html#Start-up.procedure

Comment: I install fhirbase using http://fhirbase.github.io/installation.html (Local one). and that is outdated and as per your suggestion i install fhirbase using https://github.com/fhirbase/fhirbase-plv8 and that's working for me. Thank you.